# How to write a cookie inside a static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods, httpcontext

i need to write a cookie inside static method (i need static because i want to call this method from others classes). I found solution with `HttpContex.Current`, but it is not work for me. I get this error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'

I also tried add `using System.Web.HttpContext.Current;` and i get this error

> 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

My method:

```
public static void WriteCookie(Guid token)
{ 
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("LoginControl");

    cookie.Value = token.ToString();
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(0.5);

    HttpContext.Current.Reponse.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Any suggestions? 
Thank a lot Mathew.

Comment: You have a typo `Reponse` should be `Response`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you pass the HttpContext using the method parameter?

```
public static void WriteCookie(HttpContext context, Guid token)
{ 
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("LoginControl");

    cookie.Value = token.ToString();
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(0.5);

    context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Just what I was about to say.

Comment: Thanks, but what i will insert in the argument `context`?